# How to trigger child component onPress inside parent component in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How do I trigger onPress on child component inside parent component?

I create my own custom component called `<Header>` which has props of `children` like so:

```js
const Header = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: 60,
        ...designsystems.boxShadow,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        padding: 15,
      }}>
      {children}
    </View>
  );
};
```

And I use it in screens / pages.

```js
      <Header>
        <Text style={{fontSize: theme.fontSize.xl2, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
          Menu
        </Text>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              alert('!!!!!!!!!!')
            }}>
            <View>
              <Text
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: theme.colors.primary,
                  color: theme.colors.white,
                  padding: 5,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                }}>
                Add Menu
              </Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Header>
```

I have `TouchableOpacity` inside `<Header>` which has onPress event, but it doesnt work when I press the touchable component. When I move the touchable component outside `Header` then it works. The problem is how can I get the components event (like onPress) inside `Header` work?

Comment: Move the onClick function to the parent and pass it to the child.